# how to check the permission and send the user to the correct page in php?

Tags: php, mysql

Halo everyone, I got a question for how to check the permission when the user login and send the user to the page where they suppose to be. But I just can't make it. Can anyone help?

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username
$password="123456789"; // Mysql password
$db_name="hospital_db"; // Database name
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){
$permissionssql="SELECT permissions FROM $tbl_name WHERE permissions";
$permissionssqlresult=mysql_query($permissionssql);
if(permissions==admin){
header("location:admin.php");

if(permissions==employees){
header("location:employees.php");

if(permissions==employees){
header("location:otherstaff.php");
}
}
}
}
else{
echo "Wrong username or password!";
}

?>
```

I create a permissions on my table and it is vachar.
The permission have admin/employees/otherstaff.
I'm just trying to let the system send the user to the correct page but it always doesnt work.
I'm really appreciate if there's an answer.
thanks

Comment: `permissions==employees` maybe this should be `$permissions == 'employees'` ?

Comment: $permissionssqlresult is more likely   OP is it possible for your user to have more than one permissions value from the table?  Also, look into password salting and better login methodology than this, there's some improvement to be had there

Comment: Is there `permissions` column on the `members` table? If so, there's really no need for the second query (which most likely isn't doing what you want anyway). Also, if you had error reporting turned on, I'm sure you'd be seeing all sorts of warnings/notices.